# Xresources not loaded after login

Tags: debian, x-resources

I've recently switch to Debian 10, and found problem with .Xresouces file. After login there is always some default configuration, and I can't find reason why my .Xresouces file isn't loaded.
I checked /etc/X11/Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources and /etc/gdm3/Xsession but wihtout any results.
Default content is:

```
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:   none
Xcursor.size:   24
Xcursor.theme:  Adwaita
```

Any suggestions what can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: They're probably loaded, but are either overridden by your desktop environment or ignored by apps. You can easily check if they were loaded by adding a `Foo.bar: true` line to `~/.Xresources`, and then `xrdb -query | fgrep Foo.bar`.

Comment: Thanks, but it does't show any Foo.bar key, so looks like it is not loaded. Still searching...